# Opencart 1.5.5.1 can’t send the Mail (Notification) to subscribers on admin Panel

Tags: email, notifications, admin, message, opencart

1. I've set the Mail Protoco as "MAIL"
2. I can receive the all email etc. New order, New Member
3. I try to sent email on admin Panel
4. I've type few words in the message box but it's keep on  alarm me "E-MAIL MESSAGE REQUIRED!".

Answer (score 1):

This is a known (and fixed bug). You can find all bugs on the bug tracker on the github project site. Here's the actual [bug and fix](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/438) (scroll down a little)